# Calendar set WEEK_OF_YEAR don't work properly

Tags: java, android, calendar

I have built a function to return me a date (as a String) providing the week number and the day.

My function is working perfectly on my device (Samsung Galaxy S6 under LineageOS android 7.1.2), but one of my friend, using **another android device** (android 5.1.x, that's all I know), reported me an error : the function returns him a date in the current week (the week of the real time when the function is called) whatever the week number he give.

To not bother my friends, I'm using an emulator that have the same problem. It's the default one in Android studio (Emulator Nexus_5_API_23 android 6.0).

Here is my function :

```
public static String getDayString(int weekNumber, int dayPosition) {
    DateFormat sdf = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, weekNumber);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayPosition + 2);
    return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

In my first attempts to understand the problem, I discovered that cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, weekNumber); wasn't working.

Then I putted Log.d("ClassName", String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR))); to see if the week number was properly changed from the current week number (set by getInstance()) to the desired week number (weekNumber). But the problem disappeared and the function was working perfectly...

It turns out that **when I put cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR); right after cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, weekNumber); the week number is updated but cal.set(...) alone is not working.**

Here is my "fixed" function :

```
public static String getDayString(int weekNumber, int dayPosition) {
    DateFormat sdf = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, weekNumber);
    cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayPosition + 2);
    return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

I'm extremely surprised and confused by this result. How cal.get(...) can change anything ? How I can find another way to fix this "problem" ? What is the problem with the cal.set(...) method ? Did I do something wrong or am I missing something ?

**This strange "quantum observer effect" problem doesn't appear to be present in Java in general. But only on some (not all) android devices.**